# What specs do I need to know to develop bluetooth (AVRCP 1.4) iPhone app

Tags: ios, objective-c, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, infrared

I am new to iPhone dev't and I am going to work on a project where I have to develop a bluetooth enabled iPhone app to control a vehicle stereo, and DVD player. The vehicle has a physical remote control (IR) and the aim of this project is to replace the IR with a bluetooth enabled iPhone app to control the functions that the IR does. Play, stop, next,previous etc...
The hardware can communicate with AVRCP 1.4 . I don't know every detail but that is what I know.

What knowledge do I need to implement the application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AVRCP is a Bluetooth 2.1 profile, so you will need to go through the [MFI](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mfi/) program - even then, if your are not the manufacturer for the audio unit you will probably not be able to get the solution certified as you won't be able to get the Apple chip added to the device.

To clarify my answer - According to [this document](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3647?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) iOS has support for AVRCP, in conjunction with A2DP to allow external devices (such as a car stereo) to play/pause/skip tracks being played by the iOS device.  Controlling an external device *from* your iOS device is not available to an app

Comment: Oh.. I am a bit confused. Why apple chip on the device? I am only writing a code. I think I am missing something. Please explain me in details.

Comment: I saw this and thought it was as easy as using the SDK mentioned http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11309950/control-bluetooth-audio-device-with-iphone

Comment: iOS supports some standard profiles such as headset (HSP), Audio distribution (A2DP) and Human Interface (HID), but apps cannot interact directly with peripherals using these profiles - they can just select an audio destination (A2DP or HSP) or accept keyboard input (HID).  Other Bluetooth devices/profiles can be supported through the MFI program, but it requires the device to identify itself with an Apple authentication chip.  Bluetooth Low Energy devices are supported without going through the MFI program, but only for the Attribute profile (ATT)

Comment: Thanks for the response again. Have you seen this >> https://developer.bluetooth.org/TechnologyOverview/Pages/AVRCP.aspx

Comment: Not until now, but it doesn't change the fact that iOS apps can only use the BLE ATT profile (through The Corebluetoooth framework) or need to use Externalaccessory framework as part of the MFI program

Comment: @Paulw11: I have  the same issue  and successfully paired with the hardware. but, Can I send any values (String) to the hardware via bluetooth from my iOS App.

Comment: No, you can't do that.